# Can we have frontend only Form.Items in antd Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is there a way to suppress some of the Form.Items in a Form before its sent to the backend API ? I have a couple of UI only fields in the Form and Do not want to add the backend JSON.

Comment: it needs some code.

Comment: Yes...you can. There is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have two fields Name and Age, and you want to send your name only.
You just need to remove the prop name in FormItem and in the function onFinish the values will return Name only.

```
<Form onFinish={onFinish}>
 <Form.Item label="Name" name="name">
  <Input/>
 </Form.Item>
 <Form.Item label="Age">
  <Input/>
 </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

The other way is modify your values in function onFinish then send data to the backend API